# How to describe someone who is all action? (e.g. Fortinbras in Hamlet)

Tags: adjectives

I am writing a paper on Hamlet, and am trying to describe Fortinbras as someone who is really an action-based figure. What are some adjectives that convey this?

In other words, how do I describe a "doer" as opposed to a thinker. I could not find anything online.

Comment: An action man? A mover and shaker? A doer? [Note: I am not a native speaker, so be cautious.]

Comment: Go-getter is one such synonym. In Hamlet, Shakespeare answered his critics who said that his tragic heroes all suffered from being doer's and could have avoided their fate if they had just thought a bit more.  :-)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann In the UK there is always the risk of listeners/readers picturing this guy when you say 'action man' https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Man :)

Comment: "Dives right in" is an easy way to express it(if you don't mind a phrase or an idiom).  "Get's right to it" is another but it means something more like "he's not a procrastinator".  "His wheels are always spinning" is another that relates more to being "in perpetual motion" perhaps even going from one thing to another, more than "get started right away"

Comment: Yea but I need to be very professional. I am essentially writing a literary criticism

Comment: physically inclined

Comment: Especially if you're writing literary criticism (I assume for Hamlet), I would think "agent" or "agency" could be highly appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any [really good single-word synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/doer) of "doer" that could also be considered antonyms of "thinker." So "doer" might be your best option.

In the context of the story, you might consider the word "[agent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agent)."

> One that acts or exerts power

Characters who have "[agency](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/agency/)" can be contrasted with those whose fates depend on other characters and plot devices.